# Angular 8 + Kendo Common: Error in Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive DraggableDirective

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am running latest Angular 8 with the following Kendo / Telrik packages:

```
"@telerik/kendo-draggable": "^2.2.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.4.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "1.2.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.3.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "4.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "4.7.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "6.6.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "2.0.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.6",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.4",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.8.1",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
"@progress/kendo-ui": "2020.2.617",
```

**This is my error message:**

*ERROR in Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive DraggableDirective in node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-common/dist/es2015/index.d.ts.*

The error message does not occur when I do an `ng start` but if I build with the below line, the error occurs:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk=true --commonChunk=true --deleteOutputPath=true my-app
```

Also without the node memory boost, the error still happens:

```
ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk=true --commonChunk=true --deleteOutputPath=true my-app
```